# Geiger's ace artwork

Tags: yomi

**Which of Geiger's ace moves is pictured on his ace card?**

As with all Yomi characters, Geiger has two possible options on his ace cards, with only one represented in the artwork.  Unlike other characters, it is not immediately obvious which one is being pictured.  What is the official intent on which move - Cycloid Revolution or Time Spiral Hurricane - is being shown on the card?

[image: Geiger's Ace]

Comment: I would guess Time Spiral Hurricane, as there are lots of cogs, which are traditionally associated with clocks and watches. I had a theory that the title the same orientation as the image applied to it. I couldn't find enough aces on bgg to prove/disprove it though.

Comment: (and some images on aces don't have an obvious orientation)

Comment: @tttppp Orientation is irrelevant - all characters have 4 aces with 2 facing each direction.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had a look through the Fantasy Strike website, and found a few examples of aces both ways up. Also it looks like most of Gieger's cards have cogs on them, so I'm not sure how much to read into that!

Comment: @tttppp Well, I'm not particularly interested in wild guesses.  If you don't know, you don't know.  It's ok, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Game creator David Sirlin [confirmed](http://www.fantasystrike.com/forums/index.php?threads/what-move-is-shown-on-geigers-ace.9245/#post-304808) that the move pictured is ***Cycloid Revolution***.

> The art is Cycloid Revolution. It's sort of like Venom's huge ball super in GGXX.

It can be assumed that Time Spiral Hurricane would look similar to the Sonic Hurricane of Guile from Street Fighter, an inspiration for the character.